# Memory allocation in a C program

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I have the code block below, I deleted all unnecessary parts, just left the problematic part. My purpose to fetch the time in a specific format that I need(YYYYMMDDHHmm) by `fetch_time` function. In order to `return char array`, I used `malloc`. However, the program crashes  if I run the code below like a minute. When I monitor run-time of the code by a debugging tool, the memory location that p1 points increases e.g 0x72120 for the first iteration, 0x72150 for the second iteration, and so on. So, I suspect it fails because of the memory problem. I wonder what do I do wrong and how can I solve the problem?

Btw, I guess I can solve the problem by defining a global char array and assining the time info in the sub-function. I would like to learn my mistake in the malloc usage and learn the solution. Thank you.

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    char timedate2[13];
    char *p1 = malloc(strlen(timedate2)+1);
    if(!p1){exit(1);}

    while(1){
        p1=fetch_time();
    }
}

char *fetch_time() {
    char *p;
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    char buffer [13];

    time ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
    strftime (buffer,13,"%04Y%02m%02d%02k%02M",timeinfo);
    p = (char *)malloc(sizeof(buffer));
    strcpy(p, buffer);
    return p;
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing the free(p1). You are requesting memory on each iteration, but is not being freed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks correct per see. There's one catch thought. When you call `malloc`, you are requesting some amount of memory in which you store your date string. Everytime you call `fetch_time` you will request some (other) piece of memory with a new string. You never re-use the same piece of memory and eventually run out of memory. To fix that, you need to free every piece of memory you requested which will allow the system to eventually reuse it again.

```
while(1) {
    p1=fetch_time();
    // do something with p1
    free(p1);
}
```

Also, please fix the indentation.

If you find similar problems in the future, consider using a tool like `valgrind`, it will help you a lot (google it up!).

Answer (score 2):

```
char timedate2[13];
char *p1 = malloc(strlen(timedate2)+1);
```

`timedate2` is uninitialised, so there's no way to guess (reliably) how much you try to allocate, and there's the possibility that the `strlen` call will access invalid memory and cause a segfault. Did you mean to allocate

```
char *p1 = malloc(sizeof timedate2 + 1);
```

?

But the main problem is that `fetch_time` returns a newly allocated buffer each time it is called, and that is never `free`d.

Answer (score 2):

```
char timedate2[13];
/* timedate2 is not initialized, so strlen is unpredictable at best*/
char *p1 = malloc(strlen(timedate2)+1);
```

You allocate p1 then never use it, but overwrite it with he call to fetch_time() - this is a memory leak.

fetch_time() seems ok, but it returns malloced memory which is never freed [memory leak] when you do this in a tight loop (e.g. while(1)), it will very quickly allocate all the available memory, and then **boom**

Answer (score 1):

There is a big MEMORY LEAK in your program.
First of all, you are allocating  memory to p1 in main().You then have an infinite loop for the statement `p1=fetch_time();`
In function `fetch_time()`, you are allocating memory to p and copying buffer. This address is returned to main(). You now lose the memory address for p1 which you allocated in main. 
This loop runs infinite no of times thus it would reach a stage when the memory reaches its maximum limit.

`FAULT 1`:Memory allocated to p1 not freed.
`FAULT 2`: Function fetch_time keeps on allocating memory to p in each call and does not frees it.
`FAULT 3`: Calling `malloc(strlen(timedate2)+1);`on an uninitialized string

Answer (score 1):

Modify your function as below

```
while(1){
   fetch_time(p1, strlen(timedate2) + 1);
  }
}
void fetch_time(char * time_str, int format_len)
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    char buffer [13];

    time ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
    strftime (buffer,13,"%04Y%02m%02d%02k%02M",timeinfo);
    strncpy(p, buffer, format_len);
}
```

to avoid leak memory and other unexpected errors.

Answer (score 1):

Don't You forget to free the allocated memory? The code worked for 13 minutes and did not crashed.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* fetch_time();

    int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

        char timedate2[13];
        char *p1 = malloc(strlen(timedate2)+1);
        if(!p1){exit(1);}
        free(p1);

        while(1){
               p1=fetch_time();
               free(p1);
        }
    }

    char* fetch_time() {
        char *p;
        time_t rawtime;
        struct tm * timeinfo;
        char buffer [13];

        time ( &rawtime );
        timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
        strftime (buffer,13,"%04Y%02m%02d%02k%02M",timeinfo);
        p = (char *)malloc(sizeof(buffer));
        strcpy(p, buffer);

        return p;
    }
```

I see one more issue in the lines below.

```
char timedate2[13];
char *p1 = malloc(strlen(timedate2)+1);
```

'strlen' function searches for the first symbol '\0' in the given array of chars. But in this case the content of the array 'timedate2' is undefined and the symbol '\0' may be found anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

why are you reassigning p1(already pointing to allocated memory).

Also, calling fetch_time() indefinitely will cause heap overflow.

What you can do is pass the p1(pointer) as argument to the fetch_time() and copy the timeinfo into the already allocated memory.

At last, remember to `free` the memory allocated by your program.